# CMake and multiple platforms Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, uwp

It seems, that CMake is able generate Visual Studio solution only for one platform (x86 or x64 or ARM) through setting CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM variable. This makes building UWP (Windows Store) apps more difficult because before I was able to generate store package for all platforms at once but with CMake it seems it is not possible and I must at first generate solution for each platform and then build .appx for each platform. Or I am missing something and there is some way how to solve it?

Comment: If we are talking about VS2017 I've added a solution for cross-platform configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955272/modern-way-to-set-compiler-flags-in-cross-platform-cmake-project/46132078#46132078).

Comment: Sadly its VS2015 with external CMake and now I am not able to switch to VS2017, but good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, there is no way to generate a solution with all platforms inside it directly with CMake.