# CMake: add_compile_options() error with RELEASE/DEBUG config

Tags: cmake, g++, ubuntu-16.04

What is wrong with this:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR MINGW OR ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Clang")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-W -Wall -O3 -pedantic>")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-W -Wall -O0 -g -pedantic>")
endif()
```

I get:

`g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-W -Wall -O3 -pedantic’`

If I put it like this it works:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR MINGW OR ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Clang")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-W>")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-Wall>")        
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-pedantic>")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-W>")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-Wall>")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-g>")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>")
    add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-pedantic>")
endif()
```

...but I guess that's not intended to be like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've given your example a try and could reproduce your problem:

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-W -Wall -O3 -pedantic’
```

The `add_compile_options()` command takes the parameters as a list of options, so you have to use `;` as delimiter.

The following did work in my `gcc`/`make` environment:

```py
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-W;-Wall;-O3;-pedantic>")
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-W;-Wall;-O0;-g;-pedantic>")
```

Or alternatively written as:

```py
string(
    APPEND _opts
        "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-W;-Wall;-O3;-pedantic>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-W;-Wall;-O0;-g;-pedantic>"
)
add_compile_options("${_opts}")
```

**References**

- [Modern way to set compiler flags in cross-platform cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955272/modern-way-to-set-compiler-flags-in-cross-platform-cmake-project)

Comment: Hmm...I'm pretty sure I already tried that and it didn't work. See Tsyvarev's answer.

Comment: @juzzlin Have given it a try and it did work with my CMake version 3.10.2

Answer (score 3):

Unlike to *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS* variable, which contains *single* string with options, separated by space, command `add_compile_options` accepts **separated arguments** for every option. That is, without generator expressions correct usage would be:

```
add_compile_options("-W" "-Wall" "-O3" "-pedantic")
```

So if you want to use *generator exressions*, you need to append it to every option, as you do in your second attempt.

If you have many per-configuration options and you find *manual* repeating of generator expression for every of them tedios, you may create a simple function, which does that for you. Like this one:

```
# add_compile_options_config(<CONFIG> <option> ...)
function(add_compile_options_config CONFIG)
    foreach(opt ${ARGN})
        add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:${CONFIG}>:${opt}>")
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

with usage:

```
add_compile_options_config(RELEASE "-W" "-Wall" "-O3" "-pedantic")
add_compile_options_config(DEBUG "-W" "-Wall" "-O0" "-g" "-pedantic")
```

---

If you want to add compiler options like "-W", "-O3" to *all* targets in your project but in configurations-specific manner, consider to use *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_<CONFIG>* variables:

```
string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE " -W -Wall -03 -pedantic")
```

Comment: Is it intended or a typo that you call `add_compile_options` in your example instead of the new `add_compile_options_config`?

Comment: It was a typo, fixed now. Thanks.