# CMake vs Visual Studio 2017 - RelWithDebInfo configuration

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017. I have a solution which has a different options for Debug and Release configurations, for example a runtime library. I want to create a CMakeLists.txt which can be used with Visual Studio generator, for example:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo --parallel 8
```

I need to set a correct runtime library in CMakeLists.txt. Should I use settings from the Release configuration in Visual Studio ? How CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo maps to Visual Studio configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to set a correct runtime library in CMakeLists.txt.

The canonical way of doing this is to use the `CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` variable, which sets the default value of the `MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` target property (which allows for per-target control).

As an example, to use the static runtime library, you can write the following in your CMakeLists.txt ([or better, from a toolchain or preset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68094639/2137996)):

```
set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
```

The `$<CONFIG:Debug>` [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) returns `1` at generation time if the active configuration is "Debug". Then this will reduce to `$<1:Debug>` which reduces to `Debug`. On other configurations, it will reduce to `$<0:Debug>`, which is then the empty string. You can implement your own custom logic using these generator expressions. The `$<IF:cond,then,else>` genex will be useful here.

See the documentation for `CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html

> How CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo maps to Visual Studio configurations?

Setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` with the Visual Studio generator does *absolutely nothing* because it is a *multi-config generator*. It will create one configuration for each name in the `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` list variable. There are a host of `_<CONFIG>` suffixed variables that adjust configuration-specific settings like flags and target name postfixes.

The full list may be found in the documentation, here (search for `<CONFIG>`): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html