# cmake invalid numeric arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

Windows 10
VS2019
Cmake 3.20.5

https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/tree/master/cpp

Whenever I try to run the cpp files (rest_test.cc), I would receive command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Werror' etc. for many of the flags here

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -pthread")
add_compile_options(-Wall -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -pthread)
```

I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Because there is no argument `/Werror` in MSVC? You should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Those flags are for a GCC-compatible compiler, not MSVC. You'll have to remove them from the build you've encountered (or authored).

The reason for the "invalid numeric argument" is because MSVC *numbers* its warning levels. For example, to enable all (too many) warnings, you could pass `/W4`. MSVC tries to parse `error` as a number because it is expecting to find a flag like `/W1` or `/W3`.

Such flags do not belong in the CMakeLists.txt file to begin with. Setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is bad practice for exactly the reason you just experienced. Keep this in mind as you learn CMake: only things that are *absolutely required* to build your project belong in the CMakeLists.txt. Warning flags are not absolutely required.

Comment: "Setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is a bad practice for exactly the reason you just experienced." - The only reason OP is experienced is that the project isn't prepared for MSVC, as it has no check for the compiler when adding the *compiler-specific* options. By itself, there is nothing bad in setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955272/modern-way-to-set-compiler-flags-in-cross-platform-cmake-project) about the proper ways for doing that in multiplatform manner.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I completely disagree. I would love to buy you a coffee and talk about it sometime.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I have commented on the answer you linked me to. The notion of a "compiler-specific" option goes down to the compiler _version_, not just its command-line syntax. Putting warnings (and especially warnings-as-errors) in the CMakeLists.txt (as opposed to a toolchain or preset) is a recipe for headaches.