# Clion How to Add Debug Flags?

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, cmake, clion

I used to compile my program like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 –DNDEBUG –Wall *.cpp
```

Now I moved to use Clion, where it has the following `CMakeLists.txt`, can someone kindly help me on how to add the above flags to it? (Already added C++11 flag):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(DS_WET1_PART1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(DS_WET1_PART1 main1.cpp library1.cpp library1.h linked_list.h node.h)
```

If related I'm working on macOS

Comment: `NDEBUG` is already defined in Release, MinSizeRel, and RelWithDebInfo configuration types. Warning flags are best added by setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in a preset / the CLion settings, rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: You should not set CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD, either. Instead write `target_compile_features(DS_WET1_PART1 PRIVATE cxx_std_11)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modern way to set compiler flags in cross-platform cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955272/modern-way-to-set-compiler-flags-in-cross-platform-cmake-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally, you can use :

```
add_compile_definitions(NDEBUG)
add_compile_options(-Wall)
```

Otherwise, use the target specific calls:

```
target_compile_definitions(DS_WET1_PART1 PUBLIC NDEBUG)
target_compile_options(DS_WET1_PART1 PUBLIC -Wall)
```

Comment: what is "NDEBUG"?

Comment: @Dano That's your `-DNDEBUG` preprocessor definition.

Comment: DNDEBUG != NDEBUG

Comment: @Dano Yes it is. In your command the first part, `-D` means -> define a directive. The actual directive is `NDEBUG`. that's why I only add `NDEBUG`.

Comment: *DNDEBUG != NDEBUG*  The compiler flag `-DNDEBUG` is *as if* the compile had `#define NDEBUG 1` at the very beginning.

Comment: You should not add flags without compiler checks. This breaks MSVC for no discernable reason. You should also never use directory commands like `add_compile_options` or `add_compile_definitions` in new code.