# How do I propogate compile options to subdirectories in CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

In my project I have a root `CMakeLists.txt` which defines some executables. I use `target_compile_options` to configure some settings like warnings for these executables. I have some subdirectories that compile some libraries to link with the executable. How can I propagate the compile options from the root `CMakeLists.txt` to the dependencies in subdirectories without redefining the compile options in each subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt`?

As an example, here is simplified version of my root `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(proj)

enable_language(C ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_subdirectory(src/lib/somelib)

add_executable(my_executable src/app/main.c)
target_compile_options(my_executable PUBLIC -Wpedantic) # as an example
target_link_libraries(my_executable PRIVATE somelib)
```

and the `CMakeLists.txt` in `src/lib/somelib`

```
add_library(somelib somelib.c)
target_include_directories(somelib PUBLIC .)
```

In this example, I would like for `somelib.c` to be compiled with whatever compile options are in the root `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

The place for warning flags is in the CMakePresets.json or a custom toolchain file. Only hard usage requirements belong in the CMakeLists.txt files. Your code successfully compiling has nothing to do with which warnings you use.

Furthermore, you should generally apply warning flags consistently across your project. Don't use the build system to bury problems in your code. If your compiler is throwing a false positive, add compiler-speicific pragmas (guarded by the necessary ifdefs, as needed) to locally disable warnings around the problematic code.

Here's how I would write your top-level CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(proj LANGUAGES C ASM)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11
    CACHE STRING "Version of the C standard to use")
option(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED "Enable to enforce strict C standard selection" ON)
option(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS "Enable to allow compiler-specific C extensions" OFF)

add_subdirectory(src/lib/somelib)

add_executable(my_executable src/app/main.c)
target_link_libraries(my_executable PRIVATE somelib)
```

In CMakePresets.json:

```
{
   "version": 3,
   "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
      "major": 3,
      "minor": 21,
      "patch": 0
   },
   "configurePresets": [
      {
         "name": "default",
         "displayName": "Default",
         "description": "Default build options for GCC-compatible compilers",
         "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
         "cacheVariables": {
            "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Compile with

```
$ cmake --preset default
```

I have written about the rationale for this elsewhere, so I'll post links to those references.

1. https://alexreinking.com/blog/how-to-use-cmake-without-the-agonizing-pain-part-2.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68094639/2137996

The gist is that the meaning of a warning flag is dependent on the compiler vendor, variant, and version, and so putting them in your CMakeLists.txt attaches a very brittle dependency on those things. It makes compiler upgrades and changes unnecessarily difficult and makes your build harder to distribute and reuse, even within a company.

---

Additionally, you should avoid using relative paths in `target_include_directories` and library targets should generally guard their paths with `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` to be ready for installation / export.

```
target_include_directories(
  somelib PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>")
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [cmake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html):

> **add_compile_options**
>
> Adds options to the COMPILE_OPTIONS directory property. These options are used when compiling targets from the current directory and below.

So for the given example, should be able to just add this to the top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_compile_options(-Wpedantic)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this but on a per-executable basis? i.e. all targets in the current directory and below _for the given executable_ are compiled with these options?

Comment: **Absolutely do not use directory commands in new code**.

Comment: @AlexReinking That would be good feedback if you provide a reason for it. We're all open to learning.

Comment: We need a canonical Q/A for this because it takes _forever_ to type the same thing over and over again. They are a massive foot-gun and behave in inconsistent, non-local ways. For one example, the flags get applied to targets that are defined even before the call to `add_compile_options` within the same directory, and within subdirectories, but not those targets that were defined _in subdirectories_ that were included _before_ the command.

Comment: Directory commands generally make it difficult to reason about why a flag appears on the command line of any given target and their pitfalls only compound as a project grows. That is a huge part of the reason why interface target properties were created in the first place and why the CMake devs so strongly encourage their use and prioritize their development.

Comment: @AlexReinking Fair enough.  You can considering writing an answer so that you don't have to repeat yourself if you feel that's happening. And then perhaps that would be canonical at some point. I don't mind the downvotes and leaving it here as I believe the discussion still adds value.

Answer (score 0):

## Intro

You can add a compile option using:

```
add_compile_options(-Wall)
```

or by appending to [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) (in chis case `<LANG>` is `C`) as follows:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall")
```

## Important (solution)

To propagate it to a subdirectory it needs to be called before `add_subdirectory(...)`

```
add_compile_options(-Wall)
add_subdirectory(my/source/dir/path)
```

### Other (scoped) way

You can also achieve that with `target_compile_options` by calling it from **top-level CMakeLists**, but in that case, you need to have a *target* defined and do it in the opposite order by calling `add_subdirectory` first:

```
add_subdirectory(my/source/dir/path)
target_compile_options(MyLib PUBLIC -Wall)
```

`my/source/dir/path/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(MyLib C)
# ...
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} my_lib.h my_lib.c)
```

> It should also work for executable, i.e.
> `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)`

P.S. I lost a few hours on this myself, so I hope it helps someone :)