# Setting CMAKE_C_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to the same thing without repeating oneself?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I've a CMake project containing C and C++ files, and I have a CI set up.  In the CI, I want to build my project with some additional flags to make the compiler stricter, in particular `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`.

To configure the project, I'm currently repeating myself by doing this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic"
```

As I don't want these flags baked into the CMakeLists file (since this strictness is only wanted in the CI), I'm setting the flags on the configure command in the CI.

Is there any way to rewrite this command in a way where I don't need to repeat the flags?

Note: `CMAKE_CPP_FLAGS` does not work.

Comment: `var=something; cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="$var" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="$var"`

Comment: This should be done once during configuration step so why bother?

Comment: You could use a cache initialization script or toolchain file for setting the values which allows you to reference one cmake variable when defining the other...

Comment: `CXXMAKE_C_FLAGS` isn't a thing

Answer (score 6):

This is the *exact* use case for which [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) were invented. *Please* do not hard-code `-Werror` in your build. It is a liability for your end users who might not use the exact same compiler as you. I wrote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68094639/2137996) on a related question that goes into more detail.

Here's an example `CMakePresets.json`:

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 23,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "ci-gcc",
      "displayName": "CI with GCC",
      "description": "CI build with GCC-compatible compiler",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
        "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic",
        "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then just configure your CI to build with `cmake --preset ci-gcc && cmake --build build` from your source directory.

---

As of CMake 3.24+ you should avoid writing `-Werror` literally, even in a preset, and prefer to set the cache variable [`CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR.html) to `ON` inside a preset.

Comment: Are CMake presets still applicable if different directories have different build flags? I have a situation where include paths (i.e. `-I` arguments) are conditional both on the build environment (Linux vs. Windows) and the directory. It's not clear to me, from the CMake presets documentation, if it supports distinction based on directory...? I.e. it seems to be that by using the old/not-recommended method, you would have a different `if()/else()/endif()` block to set `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` in each directory; I'm not clear what the "equivalent" would be with CMake presets...?

Comment: @StoneThrow The only ways you should set include paths are via `target_sources(... FILE_SET ...)` or `target_include_directories`, which model the semantics of public/private headers correctly. They should not be added via either the`*_FLAGS*` variables or presets.

Comment: I wonder if I might request your eyes on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77790245/how-should-i-conditionally-set-isystem-and-l-flags-in-cmake ? It is related to this question (not repeating oneself with CMake) and include paths, and I think that you have relevant expertise to weigh in on that question. Thank you in advance if you are able to help.