# How should I conditionally set -isystem and -L flags in CMake?

Tags: cmake, include-path, compiler-flags, linker-flags, cmake-presets

I have a project that is to be compiled for Linux and Windows. Compilation for the former is done in a Linux environment, and compilation for the latter is done in [w64devkit](https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit), i.e. I don't need to consider cross-compiling from a single host.

For the Windows build, all compiled files need the `-isystem $(VCPKG_DIR)/installed/x64-windows/include` compile flag, and the `-L $(VCPKG_DIR)/installed/x64-windows/lib` linker flag, where `$(VCPKG_DIR)` refers to the base location where [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/) is installed.

(For simplicity, the rest of this question focuses on the include path)

This seemed like a good application for CMake presets, something along the lines of:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 19,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "linux",
      "displayName": "Build for Linux",
      "description": "Linux build using make generator",
      "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build"
    },
    {
      "name": "win64",
      "displayName": "Build for Windows",
      "description": "Windows build using make generator",
      "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "${VCPKG_DIR}/installed/x64-windows/include"
    }
  ]
}
```

But from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72004984/5437543), I learned that the only way we should set include paths are via `target_include_directories()` (or `target_sources()`).

This makes sense, but my concern is that in my project, I have many directories (that are peers of each other), each of which has `CMakeLists.txt`. It seems, then, that I would need to add a `target_include_directories()` line in each of those `CMakeLists.txt` files, e.g.

```
target_include_directories(submodule SYSTEM ${VCPKG_DIR}/installed/x64-windows/include)
```

I.e. my concern is the *repetition* of this line across multiple `CMakeLists.txt` files. This seems like a good candidate for consolidation at one location, something to the effect "if building for Windows, always add `-I  ${VCPKG_DIR}/installed/x64-windows/include`", which seems kind of like the intent of CMake Presets.

But if this is not achievable, or not best practice, with CMake Presets, then how can I make adding that include path in each CMakeLists.txt file conditional on the build target? Would I have to do something like:

```
if(WIN64)
    target_include_directories(my_executable SYSTEM "${VCPKG_DIR}/installed/x64-windows/include")
endif()
```

?

My question is: **what is the most consolidated (least repetitive) way, or the idiomatically-correct way of conditionalizing an include-path across many CMakeLists.txt that is conditional on the build target?** Put another way: if my logic is "when building for `win64`, always include `${VCPKG_DIR}/installed/x64-windows/include` as a system include path," what is the best (or idiomatically correct) way to implement that in CMake?

Comment: So just call `include_directories` in the top CMakeLists? `I learned that the only way we should` You should prefer to use `target_include_directories`. But if you want to set a global option, you want to set a global option, so use `include_directories()`. You might be interested in toolchain files.

Comment: Why can't you use the Vcpkg toolchain file?

Comment: @AlexReinking -- tried using the vcpkg toolchain file; during compilation, I get a "No such file or directory" error for `#include <uv.h>`. But `uv.h` is present at `/path/to/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/uv.h`. I don't know exactly how the toolchain file works, but presumably, it should have set up `/path/to/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/` as a system header search directory, but it doesn't appear to have taken effect properly.

Comment: @AlexReinking - if I manually add `-isystem /path/to/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include` to the compile line, that error clears. So somehow using the toolchain file (`cmake --preset win64 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`) didn't have the desired effect of setting header search paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example for you. I did it on Linux, but the steps should be identical on Windows. I assume CMake is up to date and you have Ninja installed.

First we install vcpkg and libuv. This took about 5 minutes on my laptop.

```
$ cd dev
~/dev$ git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
~/dev$ cd vcpkg
~/dev/vcpkg$ ./bootstrap.sh -disableMetrics
~/dev/vcpkg$ vcpkg install libuv
```

Now we create an example project:

```
~/dev/vcpkg$ cd ~/dev
~/dev$ mkdir example
~/dev$ cd example
~/dev/example$ touch CMakeLists.txt main.cpp
```

Now here's the contents of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(example)

find_package(libuv REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  main PRIVATE $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:libuv::uv_a>,libuv::uv_a,libuv::uv>
)
```

And this is `main.cpp`. Just enough to test that we can find the header.

```
#include <uv.h>
int main () { return 0; }
```

Now to build this:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$HOME/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (25.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/dev/example/build
$ cmake --build build --verbose
Change Dir: '/home/alex/dev/example/build'

Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/ninja -v
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++  -isystem /home/alex/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/alex/dev/example/main.cpp
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/c++ -g  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -o main  /home/alex/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libuv.a  -lpthread  -ldl  -lrt && :
```

In the output here I can very clearly see `-isystem .../vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include`.

This works because linking to targets (i.e. either `libuv::uv` or `libuv::uv_a`) automatically triggers *propagation* of the library's public include path(s) (i.e. `vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include`) to your target. Because this target was imported via `find_package`, CMake knows to use `-isystem` rather than `-I`. It also uses the full path to the static library rather than risking name resolution issues with `-L`. This is the better behavior anyway.

---

This fragment is a bit of a hack:

```
$<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:libuv::uv_a>,libuv::uv_a,libuv::uv>
```

CMake lacks a standardized way of selecting between static and shared libraries, so every project seems to do their own thing. Libuv *happens* to name their shared library `libuv::uv` and their static library `libuv::uv_a`. Vcpkg will only ever have one available, though.

The above expression will resolve to `libuv::uv_a` if it exists and to `libuv::uv` otherwise.

---

I strongly suggest you read the documentation on using third-party libraries in CMake: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/using-dependencies/index.html

I would also peruse this documentation, especially the part on *transitive usage requirements*: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

Comment: I reproduced your minimal example; it was instructive, thank you. I found that presence/absence of the `-isystem` flag was contingent on presence/absence of the `target_link_libraries()` statement in your example CMakeLists.txt. Something not quite gelling in my mind: from reading the CMake documentation, I have the notion that `target_link_libraries()` is for setting library linking flags (e.g. `-l` (lowercase L) for `cc`)...so I don't see the connection between `target_link_libraries` and setting _include paths_ (system includes or otherwise)

Comment: CMake sits a level of abstraction above flags. Think less about flags and think more about higher-level concepts like usage requirements, dependencies, etc.

Comment: Libraries in CMake carry _usage requirements_ with them, which get propagated to the targets that link to them. Most libraries carry their headers' include path(s) as a usage requirement. The documentation I linked to explains more.

Comment: I'm understanding your point after more and deeper reading. But, given that libraries in CMake carry usage requirements, to me that then raises the question why was there ever a need for `target_include_directories()` at all? I've used it, and seen it used many times over the years, frankly, not thinking deeply about it...it actually seemed "natural" because of my `Makefile` bias: you have `-I` flags, which corresponds to `target_include_directories()`, and you have libraries to link, like `-luv`, which corresponds to `target_link_libraries()`...or so the thinking went.

Comment: Since the introduction of `target_sources(... FILE_SET ...)`, CMake has a better notion of private/public headers and can set the include directories from there. Before that, it was common to use `target_include_directories` when setting up your _own_ targets. For instance, if you have your public headers in `include/myproj` and your source files/private headers in `src/myproj` you would want to set something like `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>")`. These days it's better to use `FILE_SET`s.

Comment: Mathieu Ropert's video on modern CMake pattern had an explanation useful to my understanding here: he said `target_link_libraries()` is an "overloaded" concept in CMake...back in the old days, it was used, essentially, as a wrapper over `-l` arguments, e.g. `target_link_libraries(..., uv)` was effectively meant to translate to a `-luv` argument to `cc`...but _modern CMake_ has the concept of "modules", to where `target_link_libraries()` is kind of meant to "do everything necessary to use this module", which would translate to any necessary combination of `-I` and `-l` flags.

Comment: Yep! And it's a substantially more reliable system for it.