# How to handle shared library filename difference between Linux and Windows

Tags: c, cmake, dll, shared-libraries

This question is directly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803902/how-to-make-cmake-generated-makefiles-build-shared-libraries-with-so-extension); I've been advised to not mix many questions into one, so I'm posting individual questions around this topic.

I am working on a project whose source is built for both Linux and Windows. The project was originally built with handwritten Makefiles, because of which shared libraries are built with `.so` extensions both on Linux and Windows. After migrating the project to a `CMake`-based build, shared libraries are build with `.so` extensions on Linux, and `.dll` extensions on Windows. Because of this, the application fails at runtime because it has been hardcoded to lazy-load (`dlopen()`) shared libraries with `.so` extensions.

I believe that [the differences between dynamic link libraries and shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688536/5437543) are not relevant to the immediate need because if I rename the generated `.dll` files to `.so`, the application runs to completion successfully.

**My question is: is there standard or best-practice way to deal with the shared library filename extension difference between Linux and Windows?** I can imagine a macro-based solution, e.g.:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
#define EXTENSION ".so"
#else
#define EXTENSION ".dll"
#endif
...
  void* handle = dlopen("libfunc" EXTENSION, RTLD_NOW)
```

...but I'd like to learn if there is a widely-adopted best practice or prevailing convention, or outright correct way to handle this. In essence, the need is "when in Windows, load files with `.dll` extension; when in Linux, load files with `.so` extension."

(I am assuming that handwritten `Makefile` that created `.so` files for all platforms did so out of inexperience or convenience, etc. and that `CMake` is doing the correct or preferred thing by generating `.so` files in Linux and `.dll` files in Windows. I.e. I'm assuming that the onus is on the developer to accommodate compile-time or runtime conditionality on the extension of shared libraries he loads with `dlopen()` in his code)

---

Below are resources for a minimal, compilable example:

```
// main.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int (*fptr)(void) = NULL;
  const char* filename = "libfunc.so"; // Nota bene
  void* handle = dlopen(filename, RTLD_NOW);

  if (! handle) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  fptr = dlsym(handle, "func");
  fprintf(stdout, "fptr returns %d\n", (*fptr)());
  dlclose(handle);

  return 0;
}
```

```
// dlfcn.h
#ifndef DLFCN_H
#define DLFCN_H

#include <windows.h>

#define RTLD_NOW (1<<0)

extern inline void *dlopen(const char *lib, int flags) {
  (void) flags;

  return LoadLibraryExA(lib, NULL, 0);
}

extern inline void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *name) {
  FARPROC fp = GetProcAddress((HINSTANCE) handle, name);

  return (void *)(intptr_t)fp;
}

extern inline char *dlerror() {
  // Not thread-safe!
  static char msg[1024];
  msg[0] = '\0';

  FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                 NULL, GetLastError(), 0, msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);

  return msg;
}

extern inline int dlclose(void *handle) {
  return FreeLibrary(handle) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

```
// func.c
int func(void) {
  return 42;
}
```

```
# Makefile
.PHONY: all

CFLAGS :=

ifeq ($(shell uname), Windows_NT)
  CFLAGS += -isystem .
endif

all: libfunc.so a.out

libfunc.so: func.o
        cc -shared -fpic -o $@ $^

a.out: libfunc.so main.c
        cc -o $@ main.c ${CFLAGS}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(hello_world)

add_library(func SHARED func.c)

add_executable(a.out main.c)

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
  include_directories(SYSTEM ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()
```

---

Compiling with `make` and running on Linux:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o func.o func.c
cc -shared -fpic -o libfunc.so func.o
cc -o a.out main.c
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. ./a.out
fptr returns 42
$
```

Compiling with `cmake` and running on Linux:

```
$ cmake -B build && cmake --build build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/shared-lib-test/build
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/func.dir/func.c.o
[ 50%] Linking C shared library libfunc.so
[ 50%] Built target func
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/a.out.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable a.out
[100%] Built target a.out
$

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD/build ./build/a.out
fptr returns 42
$
```

Compiling with `make` and running in [w64devkit](https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit):

```
$ make
cc -isystem .   -c -o func.o func.c
cc -shared -fpic -o libfunc.so func.o
cc -o a.out main.c -isystem .
$
$ ./a.out
fptr returns 42
$
```

Compiling with `cmake` and running in w64devkit:

```
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -B build && cmake --build build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/w64devkit/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/w64devkit/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (3.1s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/user/dev/shared-lib-test/build
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/func.dir/func.c.obj
[ 50%] Linking C shared library libfunc.dll
[ 50%] Built target func
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/a.out.dir/main.c.obj
[100%] Linking C executable a.out.exe
[100%] Built target a.out
$
$ ./build/a.out.exe
The specified module could not be found.

$ mv ./build/libfunc.dll ./build/libfunc.so
$
$ ./build/a.out.exe
fptr returns 42
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there standard or best-practice way to deal with the shared library filename extension difference between Linux and Windows?

Your code to load the library is *already* very different -- the Windows version uses `LoadLibraryExA`, while the UNIX version uses `dlopen`.

The standard/best practice way to handle platform differences is *not* to emulate `dlopen` on Windows (as your code does), but instead to provide OS-specific `load_library` function (in different source files).

That is, most of your application doesn't care about the differences, and just calls `load_library("func");`.

The `unix.c` implements `load_library()` as (overflow checking omitted for clarity):

```
void *load_library(const char *name)
{
  char buf[1024] = "lib";
  strcpy(buf + 3, name);
  strcat(buf, ".so");
  return dlopen(buf, ...);  // dlopen("lib{name}.so")
}
```

while `windows.c` implements it as:

```
void *load_library(const char *name)
{
  char buf[1024];
  strcpy(buf, name);
  strcat(buf, ".dll");
  return LoadLibraryExA(buf, NULL, 0);  // LoadLibraryExA("{name}.dll")
}
```

You then have a selector in the `Makefile` which uses `unix.c` or `windows.c` as appropriate.