# How to set a CMake flag cache variable in presets without overwriting it?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-flags

Trying to follow best practice as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68094639/1844907) post, I'd like to set optional flags in the preset file and required flags in the toolchain/CMakelist. To be specific `CMAKE_x_FLAGS`, but I think this question applies to any other cache variable.

Toolchain file

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4")
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-exceptions")
```

CMakePresets.json

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "debug",
            "generator": "Ninja",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
            "toolchainFile": "${sourceDir}/cmake/toolchain.cmake",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS": "ON",
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
                "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "-Wall -Wextra"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My expectation, as described in the linked post, was that the preset variable is appended to the already specified variables. However, the flags specified in the Toolchain file are overwritten.
`-Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions`

This can be prevented by the following line in the CMakeLists.txt
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-exceptions")`

Seems to me this is not the way it should work? So my question is, how should I manage `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS(_INIT)` from the various files with the following idea?

- Toolchain specific flags in the toolchain file.
- Project specific flags in the CMakeLists.txt.
- Optional, warning flags in the CMakePresets.json file.

Comment: "the preset variable is appended to the already specified variables." - Not quite true. `cacheVariables` in presets are just `-D` options to `cmake`. (Generally, everything you could express via presets can be expressed via parameters to `cmake` program.) So you just set a cache variable, and handling of the cache variable is up to the project or CMake platform/toolchain files.

Comment: CMake platform files treat **cache** variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` as containing all toolchain/platform flags. So, if a user wants to set this variable (as a cache variable - there is no other option for a user), the new value is used as a **redefinition** of compiler-specific flags. A project may modify that value, but only as a non-cache one (as you do by `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-exceptions")`).

Comment: @alex-reinking when I use `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` in the presets I always loose the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT` from the toolchain. What is missing here to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

The better practice is using [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html#add-compile-options) in CMakeLists.txt.

[`CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html):

> variables will be passed before flags added by commands such as `add_compile_options()` and `target_compile_options()`.

Comment: In my project I use mainly C and C++, and I have some flags that I would like to use for just one of the two. Is it possible with the `add_compile_options()` command to add flags to one specific language?

Comment: What does prevent you from reading the linked manual page and finding the answer with examples there (BTW irrelevant to your question post)?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. Yes, it's relevant as I asked about vars for a specific language. Tried to make the question more generic to potentially help others, but apparently it is not that generic. `add_compile_options()` doesn't help me with managing flags that I want to add to just the `CPP` part (in the way described in the question) and not the `C` part. If I missed some part of the documentation, it would help to point me in the right direction. So far, I cannot find the answer in the links above.

Comment: CPP part, C preprocessor part? For C preprocessor use [`add_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html)

Comment: To give an example: due to size constraints of a small embedded target I might want to pass a different optimizer flag to the C and Cpp code.

Comment: Why do you have to pass different flags to C and C PreProcessor? Do you mean C++? Don't you have the + key on your keyboard? It was always C (C language), CPP (C preprocessor) and CXX (C++ language) in variable names.

Comment: I see we misunderstood each other here with the abbreviation. Yes, with Cpp I am referring to the C++ language, which is often used as abbreviation. You seem quite irritated, instead of helpful. So please let's just stop here, and I will wait for someone who does want to help me.

Comment: If you really carefully read the linked manual: *This command adds compile options for all languages. Use the COMPILE_LANGUAGE generator expression to specify per-language compile options*, you find the examples if you file the link to COMPILE_LANGUAGE.

Comment: **which is often used as abbreviation.** This is not true. You perhaps are confusing the .cpp file extension. CPP as an abbreviation of C++ does not make any sense, it's not shorter than C++.

Comment: Cool! I can use `target_compile_options` in the CMakeLists.txt. With this my issue is still not solved. Once I start using `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` in the presets, the values of the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT` variable in the toolchain file is lost.